# Reload UITabBarController on demand

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift5

I have the following TabBarController with 2 items. It is showing correctly.

I'm calling the `setupItems()` function from another controller when `something` changes its value.

The function is called correctly, the problem is that the `navFirstController.tabBarItem.image` is not being updated.

```swift
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupItems()
  }

  func setupItems() {
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.35
    let navFirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstController())

    let navSecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondController())
    navSecondController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.scale(image: UIImage(named: "image2")!, by: scale)
    navSecondController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -8, right: 0)

    if something == true {
      navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.scale(image: UIImage(named: "image1")!, by: scale)
    } else {
      navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.scale(image: UIImage(named: "image3")!, by: scale)
    }

    navFirstController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -8, right: 0)

    viewControllers = [navSecondController, navFirstController]
  }

}
```

I'ved tried with:

1) `viewControllers?.remove(at: 1)` at the beginning of `setupItems()`

2) `navFirstController.removeFromParent()` at the beginning of `setupItems()`

3) `self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()` at the end of `setupItems()`

4) `self.view.setNeedsLayout()`, `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()` at the end of `setupItems()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel we need to create viewControllers object again just to change tab bar image.
Just we need to get viewController object from viewControllers array and change image.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        //change image of tab bar item on button clicked
        if let tabVC = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController {
            tabVC.changeImage()
        }
    }

}


class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupItems()
    }

    func setupItems() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First")
        let navFirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
        navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Image1")

        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
        let navSecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        navSecondController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Image2")

        viewControllers = [navSecondController, navFirstController]
    }

    func changeImage() {
        if let second = viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
            second.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Image3")
            second.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Image3")
        }
    }

}
```

**Note** if you want to change selected tab bar item image then change "selectedImage" value otherwise change "image" value.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the issue you are facing in above code.

Comment: that the image is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the image's rendering mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

Try changing this:

```
  navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.scale(image: UIImage(named: "image1")!, by: scale)
```

With this:

```
  navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.scale(image: UIImage(named: "image1")!, by: scale).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

**EDIT - Sample Code**

Consider this setup:

[image]

- The initial view controller is a custom class TabBarViewController
- The red background view controller is a UIViewController with storyboard ID "First"
- The orange background view controller is a custom class SecondViewController with an IBAction and storyboard ID "Second"

The `Assets.xcassets` file has three images (40x40 png):

[image]

*TabBarViewController*

```swift
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    var something: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupItems()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    func setupItems() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First")
        let navFirstController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
        navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "image1")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
        let navSecondController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)

        navSecondController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "image2")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        navSecondController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -8, right: 0)

        if something == true {
            navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "image3")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        } else {
            navFirstController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "image1")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }

        navFirstController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -8, right: 0)

        viewControllers = [navSecondController, navFirstController]
    }

}
```

*SecondViewController*

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        //change image of tab bar item on button clicked
        if let tabVC = self.tabBarController as? TabBarViewController {
            tabVC.something = !tabVC.something
            tabVC.setupItems()
        }
    }

}
```

*OUTPUT*

[image]

Comment: only on image1 or also on image3?

Comment: Try changing this behavior on all the images

Comment: Can you try without the scale syntax, like this: `UIImage(named: "image1")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` ?

Comment: I think the problem here is that I don't have to change view controller. The image should change independently of che current view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198773/discussion-between-alxlives-and-fabersky).